# Searching across ALL sites from the Android app

Tags: feature-request, search, android-app

When using the Stack Exchange Android app, it is not possible to search for a specific word or topic across *all* the sites (you have to pick a site first then search for the problem).

But It's possible to search for a specific question or word in Stack Exchange in Google, by typing the question and adding "Stack Exchange" at the end of it, and http://stackexchange.com also got "search all sites" option: (using Google custom search)

> [image]

Can such functionality please be added to the android app as well? It's hard to know where I can find an answer for some questions or words.

Comment: Basically as all the sites are of particular technology and type like for programming you may use stackoverflow and for lifehacks or server fault you may use that site so why you want to mix all the sorted questions and answers to a single one you should know what to find and where

Comment: I didn't say that gather all questions in a single site it's a great idea to define an specific site for specific question, i mean it should be able to search and define place(site) of an specific question that maybe insignificant where to search for it. For Example it is possible in Quora to search for an specific question in searching bar and it searches in whole website and shows your question and answer.